# Unity 3d. What size graphics for iOS?

Tags: unity-game-engine, assets

I am preparing design assets for a game for iOS. These assets will be imported into Unity3d.

I have been testing using a Photoshop canvas layout at 1024 x 768 at 72dpi. This seems ok when viewed on an iphone5. But when i view on an ipad 3 the graphics look quite rough. Fluffy at the edges.

Can anyone confirm the correct photoshop canvas size and resolution I should be using

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you import your textures as Texture Type = GUI ?

Comment: And Ipad 3's native resolution is 2,048 × 1,536. If your assets get scaled to fit that resolution, sure it will look fuzzy.